# wp нумерация вывода статей

Tags: wordpress

На вп нужно добавить нумерацию вывода статей, для того, чтобы пользователь мог менять порядок вручную. Пользователь только админ. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Уточни в вопросе "пользователь" - любой посетитель или юзер с правами постинга?

Comment: только админ нужен

Answer (score 0):

Используйте плагин [Simple Custom Post Order](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-post-order/). Он позволяет менять порядок вывода любого типа записей путём перетаскивания в админке.